# Fill missing values in pandas with mean calculated per month per year

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill in missing values in my dataframe `data` with the mean calculated per month per year in pandas."Date" is the `datetime` column in the format- `YYYY-MM-DD`.I am using the following code but the mean values are incorrect:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 data["datey"] = data.Date.dt.year
 data["datem"]= data.Date.dt.month
 data.groupby(['datem','datey']).btc_total_bitcoins.transform(lambda x: 
 x.fillna(x.mean()))
 data.to_csv('test_1.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Can you also explain what is wrong?

Comment: Please post a sample dataframe and your expected result